# How to connect an ActiveMQ Client that's behind a NAT to a Server that isn't?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, rmi, jmx

I've looked online, and everything I find shows how to make a separate server to connect to the main server if it's behind a nat or firewall.

But in my case the client is behind the NAT, and the server is on the local network.

So it's set up kinda like below:

```
Client Actual:10.0.0.1 -> Client NAT:100.0.0.2:1111 <--> Server 10.0.0.0:1099
```

The Java code I use to connect to the server is as below:

```
String serviceUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.0.0.0:1099/jmxrmi"; 
String[] credentials = new String[] {"username", "password"}; 
String objectName = "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=test";
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(serviceUrl);

Map<String, String[]> env = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
env.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);

JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, env);
conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

broker = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, new ObjectName(objectName), BrokerViewMBean.class, true);
```

And the error it throws is:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.0; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

So my question is, how do I make this client behind NAT connection work?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the client to the local network, without going through the NAT, and seeing if your code works? Then you'll know if it's the NAT and not your code.

Comment: Look at https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx

Comment: Oh yes, it works just fine.
I have it running on a different machine, that isn't behind the NAT.
And I'm displaying a queues from my broker.

Comment: Also btw, to address @AlexandreCartapanis.
I read that page already, but from what I can understand of it that implementation is also for the case in which the server is behind NAT not the client.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Also just in case anyone's wondering I've also tried to, specifically set the remote rmi port etc.

Using: 
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<1099> 
com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<1098|1099>

As well as setting hostname in host file and via java.rmi.server.hostname=<servers port>

Comment: @alexandre-cartapanis

Comment: I have serious doubts regarding the IP address scheme you present. Are these actual IPs? If there are not, would it possible to write actual IPs?

Comment: Agreed. 10.0.0.0 is not a real IP address.

Comment: No no, thats some random gibberish I typed as placeholders.
It's not the real IP's. @jwatkins

Answer (score 1):

First of all: there is nothing special in with regard with network configuration for ActiveMQ to work. ActiveMQ's protocol is single port, and  can be easily routed just like most other TCP/IP protocol.

Therefore, given that the server is properly listening on its TCP port and that a client can successfully connect to it locally, then this problem can be analyzed as if it was any other network-related problem.

Can the client machine ping the server machine? It is difficult from the IP address scheme that you present to properly understand your network, but as it is presented right now, the client machine will simply assume that the server is on the local network and therefore send an ARP request asking for the MAC address of "10.0.0.0" (which will timeout because there is no such machine to answer the request) rather than forward the request to its NAT gateway. If that is indeed the problem you have, then there are three possible solutions: a) modify the network layout (have the client use a different IP scheme), b) setup a static route for the server's IP on the client machine to force its routing through the gateway, or c) add a port redirect on the gateway and have the client connect to the IP address of the gateway instead. Now solution a is not very practical, unless your setup is barely a lab configuration. Solution b is a possibility, but a really bad one. Solution C, that is setting up port redirection on the gateway, is the most common solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: The client side machine can telnet to the server machine.
And the real IPs are valid ones, you don't have to worry about that.
I will look into your suggestions with our networks guy, currently the machine in question is being used for integration testing not part of the above issue so can't access it.
@jwatkins

Answer (score 0):

Use hostnames on both sides, by setting the same `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XXX`. Be sure that hostname is resolvable on both sides. You can have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#nethostname

Comment: Thx but as stated above, I tried that and setting it in the host file.
Also I set the parameters:
com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<1099> com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<1098|1099> 
@alexandre-cartapanis